# proper way to subclass object for __getitem__() in python if emulating a dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

What's the proper way to subclass `object.__getitem__()` but fall back on the default behavior? I want to make this look like a dict that behaves dynamically (but consistently) for any possible key.

```
class MyObj(object):
    """MyObj()[k] returns 1 for any key k that ends in '_q',
       default item lookup behavior otherwise"""
    mypattern = re.compile(r'_q$')
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if self.mypattern.match(k):
            return 1
        else:
            ???
```

I tried calling `return super(TFConverter, self).__getitem__(k)` and it tells me `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: The default behavior is to raise an error saying the object doesn't support item access, which is indeed what you're getting.

Comment: What exactly is the "default item lookup behavior" you're referring to?  `MyObj` only subclasses `object`, which has no items to look up and no semantics for `x[i]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to emulate a `dict`-like interface, you should raise a `KeyError` when the item doesn't exist, just like `dict` does. This tends to be the case when your keys are strings.

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    if self.mypattern.match(k):
        return 1
    else:
        raise KeyError("Key {} does not match pattern {}".format(k, self.mypattern))
```

If you want your object to work like a `list` (generally the case if it has integer keys), you should raise an `IndexError`.

Calling `super().__getitem__` doesn't work because `object` doesn't define `__getitem__`. `__getitem__` only exists on objects which support subscripting. So if you want to delegate to a superclass's implementation of `__getitem__`, you have to make sure you're subclassing something which defines it (such as `dict`).

An alternative use-case is to return a default value when the key is not found. For example, here's a pure Python paraphrase of `collections.defaultdict` (the real version is written in C):

```
class defaultdict(dict):
    # default_factory is a function which supplies the default value when a key is not found
    def __init__(self, default_factory):
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            # the super() call works here because we are
            # subclassing dict, which supports __getitem__
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        if self.default_factory is not None:
            val = self.default_factory(key)
            self[key] = val
            return val
        raise KeyError(key)
```

Comment: ah -- thanks, that's it! Sometimes you just have to know the right question to ask.

Comment: Your `DefaultDict` implementation needs to store the factory-generated value in the dictionary before returning it.  :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `defaultdict` works a little differently from that (i.e. it overrides `__missing__` and doesn't touch `__getitem__`).

Comment: @Kevin Yes. That's why I said it was a paraphrase ;) I didn't want the precise interface of `defaultdict` to get in the way of my point, which was that you can use `__getitem__` to return a default value.

Comment: Note that the no-argument `super()` won't work in Python 2.7, which the question is tagged as. Also, you probably want to raise `KeyError(key)`. The latter point is not just a quibble, but an important part of the mapping interface.

Comment: Thanks for the notes - though it is just a paraphrase! I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no `object.__getitem__`. To be able to call the base class implementation of `__getitem__`, you need to inherit from a class that actually has one. Given that, your `super` invocation will work correctly.